# How to customize Pipes in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-command-prompt

I'm console application and want to save the output to a text file. So I do this:

```
Pi.exe > Pi.txt
```

Then open the text file and see this:

`Calculating Pi to 10,000 decimal places...`

Then I se Pi (3.14...)

How can I have the command prompt remove the `Calculating Pi to 10,000 decimal places...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrote Pi.exe or can change it, the best two options are

- Change Pi.exe to take a -q option to run 'quietly'
- Have Pi.exe output 'Calculating Pi' etc to stderr, instead of stdout

Otherwise:

- Pipe through find /v first:

  ```
  Pi.exe | find /v "Calculating Pi" > pi.txt
  ```

It will capture only lines that don't contain "Calculating Pi".